# Find/replace all files in a directory? (recursively)

Tags: replace

One task I still end up using an IDE for is project wide find-replace.

The steps are as follows.

- Select a directory to replace in
  (this could default to the projects root).
- Select the file extensions to match
  (this could initialize from other extensions variables, eg `ffip-patterns`, `projectile-other-file-alist`).
- Test the replacement, to see what it does.
- Show all replacements, giving the option to skip some.
- Execute or cancel the replacements for **all files**.

This is something I'm used to from an IDE, is there anything that gives similar functionality in Emacs.

---

Note that I've seen `dired` can almost do this, it's not too far from what I'm after, but requires opening and accepting changes in **every file**, the proceeding steps are a little cumbersome too, although I suppose they could be streamlined.

Reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Replacing-text-across-multiple-files.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `projectile-replace` `projectile-replace-regexp` for this purpose.

If the directory which you want to change is not git project still you can use this functions after creating .projectile file in this directory.

Don't forget to save after that via `projectile-save-project-buffers`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `counsel-git-grep` from package `counsel`,

API definition,

```lisp
(defun counsel-git-grep (&optional initial-input initial-directory cmd)
```

See its second parameter.

After grepping by calling `counsel-git-grep`,

- `M-x ivy-occur` (or press `C-c C-o`) to export candidates to a buffer
- `M-x ivy-wgrep-change-to-wgrep-mode` (or press `w`) to switch to `wgrep-mode`
- Edit text in buffer
- `M-x wgrep-finish-edit` (or press `C-c C-c`) to finalize the changes

See https://sam217pa.github.io/2016/09/11/nuclear-power-editing-via-ivy-and-ag/ for some use case.

In the article, the backend is `ag` instead of `git-grep`, but UI is exactly same. There are other grep backends `counsel` supports.

Comment: I don't have `ivy-occur` only `ivy-occur-mode`, this seems to put the current buffer into a non-code mode, which doesn't seem like what I'm after.

Comment: @ideasman42 , the command and its hotkey has not been changed for ages, See https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/ae9b121b834a68d11f79ca27b1e5c8790149ba2f/ivy.el#L356

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> Note that I've seen dired can almost do this, it's not too far from what I'm after, but requires opening and accepting changes in every file...

Yes, every file you marked is visited. But it doesn't require you to accept each change individually, as far as I know. If you use either `dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace` (`Q`) or `dired-do-query-replace-regexp` the behavior is that of regular `query-replace-regexp`, for the most part.  In particular, you can use `!` to replace all subsequent occurrences in the current file.

---

And if you use [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then you have a command similar to `dired-do-query-replace-regexp`, but that acts on files marked in the current listing and in subdirs, *recursively*: `diredp-do-query-replace-regexp-recursive`.

Comment: _"you can use ! to replace all subsequent occurrences in the current file."_ - thats the problem. It only operates on the current file. If you have a large code-base this makes it unusable.

Comment: Try pressing `Y` instead. That is `y` together with `Shift`.